# Is it possible to store Ajax call as an object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This isn't necessarily a "how to" question, but rather an ask to help improve upon my own understanding of JavaScript and Jquery. I've been using Jquery a lot lately in  my current job and all of my jquery involves a lot of AJAX calls. In several files I have at least 6 ajax calls for different situations and I was wondering if there was a more efficient way to do this from building the code. One of my colleagues who doesn't code suggested turning the AJAX call into a property and passing along arguments. Is this even possible? If not, is there a better and easier way to handle multiple AJAX calls in one file?

Thank you for your input and I hope to learn a lot from this

Here is an example of one of our AJAX calls

```
$.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '',
      data: {
        method: 'custCodeData',
        custCode: $('#custCode').val()
      },
      dataType: 'JSON',
      success: function (data) {
        var array = data.DATA;
        $("#response tr:not(:first)").remove();
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
          var newRow = table.insertRow();
          for (var j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
            if (j < 7) {
              var cell = newRow.insertCell(j);
              cell.innerHTML = array[i][j];
            }

            if (j === 0) {
              if (array[i][0] == false) {
                cell.innerHTML = "No";
              }
              if (array[i][0] == true) {
                cell.innerHTML = "Yes";
              }
            }

            if (j === 2) {
              if (array[i][8] == false) {
                cell.innerHTML = `<a href='/buying/quicklink/index.cfm?Passed_CustomerID=${array[i][7]}'>${array[i][2]}     </a><i class="fa fa-arrow-down" aria-hidden="true" ONMOUSEOVER="return overlib('Incomming Customer', FGCOLOR, 'FFFFCC',  BORDER, 2, BGCOLOR, '000000', TEXTFONTCLASS, 'RollOver', WRAP);" ONMOUSEOUT="nd();"></i>`
              } else if (array[i][8] = true) {
                cell.innerHTML = `<a href='/buying/quicklink/index.cfm?Passed_CustomerID=${array[i][7]}'>${array[i][2]}         </a><i class="fa fa-arrow-up" aria-hidden="true" ONMOUSEOVER="return overlib('Outgoing Customer', FGCOLOR, 'FFFFCC',  BORDER, 2, BGCOLOR, '000000', TEXTFONTCLASS, 'RollOver', WRAP);" ONMOUSEOUT="nd();"></i>`
              }
            }
          }
        }
        $("#response tr:contains(Yes)").css({"background-color": "#ff0000", "color": "#FFF"});
      }
    })
```

Comment: FYI: One huge paragraph is hard to read.

Comment: *if there was a more efficient way to do this from building the code*? *Here is an example of one of our AJAX calls*? I'm not really clear what your expecting here?

Comment: So make a function and pass in arguments with the part of code that needs to change.... Really unclear what you expect out of this.  Make the part that is the same and use variables for the parts that are different.

Comment: "Six AJAX calls in one file" doesn't mean much. Letting us see one of them, ditto. Do they share functionality? How similar are they? If they are, then they can be refactored so that the shared stuff is not repeated needlessly. If everything is different, you gain nothing by changing things around. Imagine you have a cake shop. If you make a lot of cakes where you sprinkle "Happy 50th anniversary", having a permanent template for it in a drawer makes sense. It makes no sense to store a permanent template for "Rashid", "Anna-Mae" or "Amadan", as you'll use more space than save on time.

Comment: @Amadan there are 6 ajax calls that are just like the one I've shown above. They all share the same functionality, just the methods are changed. That's what I was asking. How to avoid repeating code needlessly.

Comment: *just the methods are changed*....right... what methods?

Comment: @Liam I have 6 ajax calls just like the one I've shared and I am trying to see if there is a way I can improve upon that. They all share the same functionality and work the same exact way.

Comment: In that case, stuff the whole AJAX thing in a function and call `doTheSameExactAJAXThingAgain()` when you need it.

Comment: `method: 'custCodeData'` is what I am referring to. There are `custCodeData, compNameData, compConData, custPhoneData, custFaxData, custEmailData` respectively

Comment: [Generally speaking, a function is a "subprogram" that can be called by code external (or internal in the case of recursion) to the function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions)

Comment: fine, that's just a parameter to your function `doTheSameExactAJAXThingAgain('custCodeData')`

Comment: I hate to ask, but could one of you provide a small example? Thank you everyone

Comment: enjoy https://stackoverflow.com/a/52835676/542251

Comment: BTW, you might see references to DRYing up your code, or WET code, in relation to what we just discussed. [Wikipedia on DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function doTheSameExactAJAXThingAgain(method){
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '',
      data: {
        method: method,//<- METHOD here
        custCode: $('#custCode').val()
      },
      dataType: 'JSON',
      //...etc
}

doTheSameExactAJAXThingAgain('custCodeData');
doTheSameExactAJAXThingAgain('compNameData');
//etc.
```